# pytest-4.x.x: How to report SKIPPED tests like XFAILED?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, automated-tests, pytest

When a test is xfailed the reason that is printed reports about test file, test class and test case, while the skipped test case reports only test file and a line where skip is called.

Here is a test example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env pytest

import pytest

@pytest.mark.xfail(reason="Reason of failure")
def test_1():
    pytest.fail("This will fail here")

@pytest.mark.skip(reason="Reason of skipping")
def test_2():
    pytest.fail("This will fail here")
```

This is the actual result:

```sh
pytest test_file.py -rsx
============================= test session starts =============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-4.4.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.9.0
rootdir: /home/ashot/questions
collected 2 items                                                             

test_file.py xs                                                         [100%]
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
SKIPPED [1] test_file.py:9: Reason of skipping
XFAIL test_file.py::test_1
  Reason of failure

==================== 1 skipped, 1 xfailed in 0.05 seconds =====================
```

But I would expect to get something like:

```sh
pytest test_file.py -rsx
============================= test session starts =============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-4.4.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.9.0
rootdir: /home/ashot/questions
collected 2 items                                                             

test_file.py xs                                                         [100%]
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
XFAIL test_file.py::test_1: Reason of failure
SKIPPED test_file.py::test_2: Reason of skipping

==================== 1 skipped, 1 xfailed in 0.05 seconds =====================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](/questions/55806373/pytest-4-x-x-how-to-report-skipped-tests-like-xfailed/55815643#55815643) I've found the following solution that works perfectly for me.
I've created `conftest.py` file in the root of my test suite with the following content:

```py
import _pytest.skipping as s

def show_xfailed(tr, lines):
    for rep in tr.stats.get("xfailed", []):
        pos = tr.config.cwd_relative_nodeid(rep.nodeid)
        reason = rep.wasxfail
        s = "XFAIL\t%s" % pos
        if reason:
            s += ": " + str(reason)
        lines.append(s)

s.REPORTCHAR_ACTIONS["x"] = show_xfailed

def show_skipped(tr, lines):
    for rep in tr.stats.get("skipped", []):
        pos = tr.config.cwd_relative_nodeid(rep.nodeid)
        reason = rep.longrepr[-1]
        if reason.startswith("Skipped: "):
            reason = reason[9:]
        verbose_word = s._get_report_str(tr.config, report=rep)
        lines.append("%s\t%s: %s" % (verbose_word, pos, reason))

s.REPORTCHAR_ACTIONS["s"] = show_skipped
s.REPORTCHAR_ACTIONS["S"] = show_skipped
```

And now I'm getting to following output:

```sh
./test_file.py -rsx
============================= test session starts =============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-4.4.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.9.0
rootdir: /home/ashot/questions
collected 2 items                                                             

test_file.py xs                                                         [100%]
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
SKIPPED test_file.py::test_2: Reason of skipping
XFAIL   test_file.py::test_1: Reason of failure

==================== 1 skipped, 1 xfailed in 0.05 seconds =====================
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible ways to achieve this. The quick and dirty way: just redefine `_pytest.skipping.show_xfailed` in your `test_file.py`:

```
import _pytest

def custom_show_xfailed(terminalreporter, lines):
    xfailed = terminalreporter.stats.get("xfailed")
    if xfailed:
        for rep in xfailed:
            pos = terminalreporter.config.cwd_relative_nodeid(rep.nodeid)
            reason = rep.wasxfail
            s = "XFAIL %s" % (pos,)
            if reason:
                s += ": " + str(reason)
            lines.append(s)

# show_xfailed_bkp = _pytest.skipping.show_xfailed
_pytest.skipping.show_xfailed = custom_show_xfailed

... your tests
```

The (not so) clean way: create a `conftest.py` file in the same directory as your `test_file.py`, and add a hook:

```
import pytest
import _pytest

def custom_show_xfailed(terminalreporter, lines):
    xfailed = terminalreporter.stats.get("xfailed")
    if xfailed:
        for rep in xfailed:
            pos = terminalreporter.config.cwd_relative_nodeid(rep.nodeid)
            reason = rep.wasxfail
            s = "XFAIL %s" % (pos,)
            if reason:
                s += ": " + str(reason)
            lines.append(s)

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter):
    tr = terminalreporter
    if not tr.reportchars:
        return

    lines = []
    for char in tr.reportchars:
        if char == "x":
            custom_show_xfailed(terminalreporter, lines)
        elif char == "X":
            _pytest.skipping.show_xpassed(terminalreporter, lines)
        elif char in "fF":
            _pytest.skipping.show_simple(terminalreporter, lines, 'failed', "FAIL %s")
        elif char in "sS":
            _pytest.skipping.show_skipped(terminalreporter, lines)
        elif char == "E":
            _pytest.skipping.show_simple(terminalreporter, lines, 'error', "ERROR %s")
        elif char == 'p':
            _pytest.skipping.show_simple(terminalreporter, lines, 'passed', "PASSED %s")

    if lines:
        tr._tw.sep("=", "short test summary info")
        for line in lines:
            tr._tw.line(line)

    tr.reportchars = [] # to avoid further output
```

The second method is overkill, because you have to redefine the whole `pytest_terminal_summary`.